# Custom USB HID device keeps disconnecting and reconneting

Tags: usb, udev, usb-device, hid

I have a little home-made measurement device, which outputs it data by USB HID to a connected computer.  It works fine under Windows, but under Linux (I tested it on two different computers, both a recent Debian) it just connects for a few seconds, then disconnects and immediately reconnects, and so on.

Extract out of the syslog:

```
Oct  1 17:17:26 r2 kernel: [20446.158839] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 76
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 kernel: [20446.804678] usb 1-6: new low-speed USB device number 77 using xhci_hcd
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 kernel: [20446.963314] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=16c0, idProduct=05df, bcdDevice= 1.00
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 kernel: [20446.963317] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 kernel: [20446.963318] usb 1-6: Product: Miniskop 1.3
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 kernel: [20446.963319] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: obdev.at
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 77: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6"
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 77 was not an MTP device
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 kernel: [20446.970031] input: obdev.at Miniskop 1.3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/0003:16C0:05DF.02B3/input/input704
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 kernel: [20446.970203] hid-generic 0003:16C0:05DF.02B3: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.01 Device [obdev.at Miniskop 1.3] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 77: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6"
Oct  1 17:17:27 r2 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 77 was not an MTP device
Oct  1 17:17:31 r2 kernel: [20451.406128] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 77
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 kernel: [20452.048706] usb 1-6: new low-speed USB device number 78 using xhci_hcd
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 kernel: [20452.207314] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=16c0, idProduct=05df, bcdDevice= 1.00
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 kernel: [20452.207317] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 kernel: [20452.207319] usb 1-6: Product: Miniskop 1.3
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 kernel: [20452.207320] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: obdev.at
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 78: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6"
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 78 was not an MTP device
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 kernel: [20452.214050] input: obdev.at Miniskop 1.3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/0003:16C0:05DF.02B4/input/input705
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 kernel: [20452.214127] hid-generic 0003:16C0:05DF.02B4: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.01 Device [obdev.at Miniskop 1.3] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 78: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6"
Oct  1 17:17:32 r2 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 78 was not an MTP device
Oct  1 17:17:36 r2 kernel: [20456.638943] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 78
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 kernel: [20457.288758] usb 1-6: new low-speed USB device number 79 using xhci_hcd
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 kernel: [20457.451322] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=16c0, idProduct=05df, bcdDevice= 1.00
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 kernel: [20457.451325] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 kernel: [20457.451326] usb 1-6: Product: Miniskop 1.3
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 kernel: [20457.451327] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: obdev.at
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 79: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6"
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 79 was not an MTP device
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 kernel: [20457.458007] input: obdev.at Miniskop 1.3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/0003:16C0:05DF.02B5/input/input706
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 kernel: [20457.458060] hid-generic 0003:16C0:05DF.02B5: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.01 Device [obdev.at Miniskop 1.3] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 79: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6"
Oct  1 17:17:37 r2 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 79 was not an MTP device
```

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/994338/how-can-i-fix-my-ups-repeatedly-disconnecting-and-reconnecting) very similar looking question about the same behavior of an UPS, but I don't know how (if even possible) to adapt it to my problem.

Comment: Maybe try changing your udev rules or look at the udev rules that detect 'MTP devices' and try to change your device such that it doesn't match that rule. This post suggests that all unmatched devices might be categorized as MTP: https://superuser.com/questions/1206664/disable-mtp-udev-rules-for-specific-device-so-it-can-be-mount-as-a-usb-mass-stor. So you could also try making a rule to match your device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't help.  Only the lines about MTP devices stopped to appear, but it still reconnects all the time.